# email attachments using log4j.smtpAppender

Tags: java, log4j

can i trigger an email with attachment(log files) using the log4j.smtpAppender.

I'm currently using this appender to trigger emails for error and fatal level exceptions. Can I add the log file in the same email as attachment

```
log4j.appender.email=org.apache.log4j.net.SMTPAppender
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static void emailAttachment
              throws AddressException, MessagingException{

  String host = mail.company.com;
  String from = user@company.com;
  String to = user2@company.com;
  String cc = user3@company.com;

  Properties props = System.getProperties();

  props.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
  Session session = Session.getInstance(props, null);

  MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
  message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
  message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(to));
  message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.CC, new InternetAddress(cc));

  message.setSubject("Email Notification");
  MimeBodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();

  messageBodyPart.setText("email Body");

  Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
  multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
  messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
  DataSource source = new FileDataSource(fileAttachment);
  messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
  messageBodyPart.setFileName("attachment.pdf");
  multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

  message.setContent(multipart);

  Transport.send( message );

}
```

Source: [jGuru.com](http://www.jguru.com/faq/view.jsp?EID=30251)

Answer (score 1):

I think you can't send a log file in the same email. You can of course configure several appenders to log your data: example one sending email (SMTPAppender), other printing to stdout (ConsoleAppender), etc.

Besides, I don't think it is a good idea to attach a log file to the same email: the log file will keep growing each time a new email is sent, and suppose your log is about 5MB long...then logging will eat you a big chunk of processing power.

Comment: Not exactly the log file. but the other file which is 100KB. I found javaMail as better solution for my requirements